# Stop SlidingPaneLayout from going too far

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-sliding

I have a SlidingPaneLayout which contains a fragment in the left hand pane.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity$DummySectionFragment"
    >

    <fragment
        android:name="com.bolldorf.cnpmoebel.widgets.PlaceChooserFragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_place_chooser"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_place_chooser"
        android:layout_weight="0.3" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    < ... more stuff here ... >
        </RelativeLayout>


</android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout>
```

The fragment is not very wide, but it's width can change a little as it consists of dynamically loaded spinners.

How can I get the SlidingPaneLayout to stop opening once it shows the full fragment?

Clarification: Before the panel is slid out, I can see the whole of the right-hand (or bottom in the xml) pane, and the left-hand pane is hidden.

After sliding, I can see about 10% of the right-hand pane as it is moved right, and 90% of the left-hand pane.

What I would like is to see 30% of the left hand pane, and 60% of the right-hand pane, ie I would like the slide movement to stop sooner.

Comment: can you make your question a little clearer?

Answer (score 0):

This can by solved by setting "android:layout_marginLeft" in your fragment tag in xml, hope it will help you.